# Is there a way to toggle Aero Peek after a certain amount of inactivity (like a screensaver) in Windows 7?

Tags: desktop, screensaver, aero-peek

I'm basically looking for Aero Peek style functionality that triggers after a certain period of inactivity. Is there any way of achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use scheduled tasks to execute a command (after a period of inactivity of your choice) which will call the "Show Desktop" command.  [Follow these steps](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/windows-7/create-a-show-desktop-icon-in-windows-7/) to create a "Show Desktop" command as a file, and then [create a new scheduled task](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/schedule-a-task) which launches the file.

Alternatively, if you simply want to use the Aero-peak functionality instead of actually minimizing the windows, you can use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) to create an executable to move your mouse to the bottom right corner (or wherever else your Aero-peak button is).  You can then run the executable again as a scheduled task.

The AutoIt script would be trivial to complete, as you only need one single line.  Just use the `Mouse Move` function, [as documented here](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/MouseMove.htm).  For example, if you have a screen resolution of 1440x900, enter the following line into Notepad, and save the file as "Aeropeak.au3" (and execute it as your scheduled task):

```
MouseMove(1440, 900, 0)
```

Comment: Actually I used AutoIt to compile an executable, changed the extension to .scr and set it as my screensaver. At one point I was looking for a way to compile VBscript to .exe to invoke the ToggleDesktop API but I never found any true freeware. This way is better anyway because I can simply move my mouse out of the Peek area when I get back to "dismiss" the screensaver. Thanks!